# how do i add a new property to an array in angular way binding with prefix field

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-material

I have a form with 3 options to select, to which I also have 3 objects and at the same time the 3 objects, they have 3 properties, I want to pass the prefix string, once I select 1 option in the form

Component.ts

```
products = [
    {name: "eggs", value: 1, prefix: "EGS"}
    {name: "beans", value: 3, prefix: "BNS"}
    {name: "rice", value: 5, prefix: "RCE" }
]

validatorsfields() {
   this.liteFormgroup = this.formBuilder.group({
   nameofProduct: ['', Validators.required],
   prefix: ['']
   })   
}
```

HTML

```
.......="ngForm" [formGroup]="liteFormGroup"
<mat-select placeholder="Name of producst" formControlName="nameofProduct" name="nameofProduct" id="nameofProduct">
    <mat-option *ngFor= let product of products [value]="product.value id="{{product.value}}">
        {{product.name}}
    <mat-option>
```

I want to send in addition to the "value" property, I want to send the prefix property in the same selection of the object, grateful for your help and attention

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you try to show what you want to achieve? (even if the syntax will be incorrect ...)

Comment: I want to send the property the "prefix" array in the id field too, when they select an option in the form @Felix